# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined when running Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Suddenly one of my Shiny apps, hosted on Shiny Server, stopped loading properly. The Shinydashboard element would load but then nothing else.

Inspecting the developer tools console shows up an error as below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at escapeSelector (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:5:14)
    at hide_spinner (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:17:24)
    at update_spinner (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:31:5)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:52:3)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

This is preceded by a series of warnings like: DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: ..../crosstalk.min.js.map

The app runs absolutely fine locally on RStudio.

It's difficult to provide a reprex because it only seems to occur on the live Shiny Server version - I assumed it could be something related to the version of Shiny Server or Shiny but that doesn't appear to have solved anything.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Did you find a solution to this issue ? I have exactly the same problem : my shiny app works fine on Rstudio, but crashes from some remote clients. Thanks

Comment: Hi! So if I remember currently this turned out to be related to the shinycsswidgets package, do you use that by any chance? I removed those and it started working on the live server, and haven't got round to seeing if that is fixed yet.

Comment: I get a bunch of warnings (in the JS console) of a slow network before it crashes with the above error. Naturally, it works locally.